# GoogleMap is already defined in this compilation unit

Tags: android

```
Error:(6, 1) error: GoogleMap is already defined in this compilation unit while building project from android studio.
```

How to fix this problem

This is the dependencies i used

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745803/gradle-error-attribute-xxx-has-already-been-defined-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line in your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

---

The last version of Google Play Services now uses appcompat-v7, so u can't use it with Google Maps. You have to use only appcompat-v7 or the previous version of Google services!

Read also [Gradle error "Attribute "xxx" has already been defined" in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745803/gradle-error-attribute-xxx-has-already-been-defined-in-android-studio).