# Error: Attribute 'SrcCompat' has already been defined

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, build-tools

Every time I try to build or generate signed APK I get the above error.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37283686/5588854) is similar but no working solution has been suggested, yet.

A snap of my BUILD.GRADLE dependencies:

[image]

A snap of my Error Log:

[image]

Support Library Updated

[[image]]

Answer (score 2):

finally got a way round it. Renewed the project and started importing one lib at a time to the point I got the error. Apparently this third party lib 
 '*com.github.ozodrukh:RippleDrawable:2.0.0*' defined srcCompat just like AppCompat does. So I commented it out and it Builds just fine...